# Error C2888 migrating from VC9 to VC10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, migration

I am trying to compile solutions and projects on MSVC++ 10 that worked fine in MSVC++ 9, and I am having trouble with it, mostly getting the following message:

**error C2888:** *'std::hash' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'tr1'*

on the following code:

```
namespace std {
namespace tr1 {

template <>
struct hash< Rubedo::eChannelFamily >
{
    std::size_t operator()( const Rubedo::eChannelFamily& Key ) const
    {
        return ( int ) Key;
    }
};
}}
```

I would be perfectly happy if I could do one of the following:

- Modify the code to fix the bugs and compile cleanly;
- Force the compiler to behave like MSVC++ 9.0.

How would I do something like that?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash` is in namespace `std` in VS2010, as it's part of C++0x's Standard library, not `std::tr1`. Just remove the tr1 section and the compiler should be fine.

```
template<> class std::hash< Rubedo::eChannelFamily >>
    : public std::unary_function<const Rubedo::eChannelFamily, size_t>
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const Rubedo::eChannelFamily& ref) const {
        return ( int ) ref;
    }
};
```

This is a fairly trivial modification of a hash I have for my own type which compiles successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You've to inherit `unary_function` like this and `tr1` is not needed anymore,

```
namespace std 
 {
       template <>
       struct hash<Rubedo::eChannelFamily> : public unary_function<Rubedo::eChannelFamily, size_t>
       {
             size_t operator()(const Rubedo::eChannelFamily& key) const
             {
                   return (size_t) key;
             }
      };
 }
```

Comment: You know, he specified what CustomType and //your code is in his OP.

Comment: @DeadMG : yup. I replaced YourCustomType with his type and code. :-)